# SF Choose-your-own-adventure ID: Space junks, Darth Vader lookalike, and tentacle monsters

Tags: story-identification, choose-your-own-adventure

I'm trying to find a "choose-your-own-adventure" type book I read as a kid in the early or mid 1990's in Canada. Here's what I remember:

**About the book itself**

- Large trade-paperback format, and fairly thin (I'd say maybe 40 pages or so).
- More art-heavy than text; each page had a full-page image.
- The book itself, as well as three similar books (all SF, with a similar art style) were advertised on the back.

**About the story**

- The villain was a space pirate leader who looked a lot like Darth Vader (black armour, cape, etc.)
- Spacecraft were referred to as "space junks" - its where I first heard of that type of craft. Unfortunately, searching google for this term doesn't give me any useful results.
- There was a black swamp alien that had tentacles and a head on a long neck, with red eyes facing in all directions. One choice you could make was to shoot its tentacles or its head.
- There was a really old space pirate, with a white beard and visored helmet you had to "fight".
- There was a space dungeon with several aliens chained to the wall. There was a human space prince in a forcefield you had to rescue.

I had this books for years, but I had accidentally donated it to a used bookstore a while back. Thanks in advance for any help identifying this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it: It is *[Kidnap in Space](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3945784-kidnap-in-space-integalactic-quest)* by Peter Milligan, a part of the *Intergalactic Quest* series of choose-your-own-adventure books.

[image: Kidnap in Space]

Comment: How did you find it?

Comment: I basically had to do a manual search through Demian's Gamebook Web Page (https://gamebooks.org/Item/1328/Show), which I had in turn come across via a generic search for choose-your-own-adventure books. It was neither elegant nor fun, but I got my result in the end.

Comment: They could have proofread that title better XD